# Get.defaultdialog causes application crashes

Tags: flutter

I have been working on this issue for hours. The problem is that if i create a new flutter project add this line of code.

```
  return Container(child: ElevatedButton(child: Text("ccc"),onPressed: (){
  Get.defaultDialog(
    title: "GeeksforGeeks",
    middleText: "Hello world!",
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    titleStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    middleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

     );
    },),);
```

I am getting  this error.

```
  Null check operator used on a null value
```

I have tried reinstal package and other things(flutter doctor,pub get,flutter clean).But the problem persists.

Comment: are you using getx?

Comment: Yes I am using getx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it and I noticed the user has to use "GetMaterialApp" instead of "MaterialApp".
After you replace you could get what you expect to have.

Fig1. [About Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get)
[image]
Before

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
```

After

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
```

Fig2. The error I got before replacing "MaterialApp" with "GetMaterialApp"
[image]

Fig3. the picture I got after changed. It works.

[image]